# Rails 4/ UJS - ActionController::UnknownFormat - provide user with a way to directly open page with modal already opened

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ujs

In my Ruby on Rails application, I am using Ajax through Rails' UJS (unobtrusive JavaScript).

It's perfectly working: when a user is on a Deal page, and when he then clicks on a certain textual link, the Ajax call is made and the modal with the distant content is loaded.

**But I'd like to give a way to users to arrive directly on the page WITH the modal ALREADY OPENED, without him needing to load the Deal page and then click on the textual link**. 
For example a user could receive en email and click on it and he would straight away arrive on Deal Page with the modal already opened.

But it's not working, when I take the route of the modal (see code below), and type in the browser http://myapp.com/deals/:id/deal_opportunities_modal , then it's giving the following error:

Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 29ms

ActionController::UnknownFormat - ActionController::UnknownFormat:
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:218:in `respond_to'
  app/controllers/deals_controller.rb:70:in`show_opportunities'

Here are my files:

controller/deals_controller.rb

```
# used so that old urls created for deals redirects to the new ones created
# indeed with friendly_id, the url is taken from the title :/deals/title
# but if we edit the deal title to deal/title2, the old url was still    working
# we need to redirect the old url
# source - github.com/norman/friendly_id/issues/385
before_filter :find_deal,
   :only => [  :showcase ]
before_filter :ensure_canonical_deal_path!,
  :only => [  :showcase ] 

def showcase    
    @deal = Deal.friendly.find(params[:id])   

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # showcase.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @deal }
    end
end 

def show_opportunities
    @deal = Deal.friendly.find(params[:id])
    @opportunity = Opportunity.where('deal_id = ? AND deal_type = ?',
                             @deal.id, "high tech").first

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
end

protected

def find_deal
   @deal = Deal.friendly.find params[:id]
end
def ensure_canonical_deal_path!
   if request.path != deal_page_path(@deal)
        redirect_to deal_page_path(@deal, :format => params[:format]), :status => :moved_permanently
        return false
   end
end
```

app/views/deals/showcase.html.erb

```
<% if @deal.present? %>
   this is the beginning
   <%= render 'deals/deal_info_zone' %>
   this is the end
<% end %>
```

views/deals/_deal_info_zone.html.erb

```
<div id="zoneA">      
  <div style="color:red;padding-top: 150px;">
    <%= link_to "view infos of the latest Opportunity", deal_opportunities_modal_path, remote: true %>
  </div>
</div>
```

views/deals/deal_opportunities_modal.js.erb

Here is the modal trigger via Ajax: views/deals/opportunity_modal. Note here how I tried here to pass Deal but without success so that the line

```
$('body').append('<%= j render partial: "deals/deal_opportunities_modal" %>');
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

/app/views/deals/_deal_opportunities_modal.html.erb

Here is the modal view/content now:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="modal-body"> 

          this the the latest opportunity: <%= @opportunity.name %> <br/>     

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

routes.rb

```
match '/deals/:id', # this is the Deal page
    to:   'deals#showcase',
    via:  'get',
    as:   :deal_page

match '/deals/:id/opportunity_modal',
  to: 'deals#show_opportunities',
  via: 'get',
  as: :deal_opportunities_modal
```

How to achieve this, i.e. how to create a sort of route/URL that when used by a user, he arrives on Deal page with the modal 'show_opportunites' **already open.**

I heard about js-routes but it seems to be useful for other purposes (i.E use  Rails routes inside javascript files).

Also is there a security issue if I enable the user to reach the page with the already-opened modal like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a browser open to a controller action that is only available as JS.

The way I see it, since you already have a button on the deals page that opens the modal, just trigger it if they hit the right URL

**Use a route with a separate controller actiona that calls the same view, store a variable to tell the view to use the modal**

Like so:

- Given the link **"/deals/24/opportunities"** or any other naming convention create a route:

---

```
get '/deals/:id/opportunities', to: "deals#opportunities", as: deal_opportunities
```

- In your controller, create an action that uses the same view as `showcase` but pass a variable to the view to check for the param, `@show_modal = true`

---

```
def opportunities
    @show_modal = true
    @deal = Deal.friendly.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render action: "/deals/show" }
    end
end
```

- In your `showcase` view, if show_modal exists, then use javascript to trigger the button you already have in the view to call the modal manually

---

```
<%= if @show_modal %>  
  <script type="text/javascript">
     $(window).load(function(){
        $("a.deals-button").trigger("click");
    });
  </script>
<% end %>
```